# assign variable value of another variable depending third variable

Tags: python

I have 4 variables in my python code which look like this:

```
dev_login=os.environ['DEV_LOGIN']
dev_password=os.environ['DEV_PASSWORD']
prod_login=os.environ['PROD_LOGIN']
prod_password=os.environ['PROD_PASSWORD']
```

And I have a function which receives one of two environments as an attribute like:

```
somefunction(env)
```

in `somefunction` I need to use 2 of the above variables depending the `env` attribute. So if I call `somefunction(dev)` then the login and password variables in the function should be assigned like this:

```
login=dev_login
password=dev_password
```

using if isn't the right way for me, as I may have 10+ `env`s, and don't want to add some code when new environment is added.
Tried this way but it didn't work:

```
def somefunctions(env):
    login=+env+"_login"
```

Comment: Why not pass the prefix, and get e.g. `login = os.environ[prefix + "_LOGIN"]`? Or a dictionary `{ "dev_login: os.environ["DEV_LOGIN"], ...}`. Either is far more straightforward than juggling dynamic variable names.

Comment: @jonrsharpe using prefix to get the variable from os envvar is the easiest way to do what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def some_func(input):
    login = '{}_LOGIN'.format(input.upper())
    password = '{}_PASSWORD'.format(input.upper())

    print(login, password)

some_func('env')
some_func('dev')

>> ENV_LOGIN ENV_PASSWORD
>> DEV_LOGIN DEV_PASSWORD
```

You can then insert the variables as needed:

```
dev_login=os.environ[login] # 'DEV_LOGIN'
dev_password=os.environ[password] # 'DEV_PASSWORD'
```